# Having Problems Installing node-xmpp-server on My 64-bit Windows System

Tags: node.js, xmpp

Can anybody help me with this error I keep getting trying to install `node-xmpp-server`. I already installed all the dependencies.

```
C:\windows\system32\node_modules\node-xmpp-server\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node
_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebu
ild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\windows\system32\node_modules\node-xmpp-server\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferut
il) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configur
e.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node
-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\windows\system32\node_modules\node-xmpp-server\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
```